# Is it possible to search gerbers for specific parts?

Tags: gerber

I am using [GC-Prevue](http://www.graphicode.com/GC-Prevue_Gerber_Viewer) to view gerbers I have been supplied.

When I am looking for a part, I typically search through the silkscreen until I find it, (I do not have the PCB design file).  This is really time consuming, very annoying and shockingly inefficient.

Given I have the pick and place data, it should be possible to match with the gerber data.

Is there anyway to search for a component with only the gerber and pick and place data?

Comment: The pick-and-place file should give you a set of XY coordinates, which you can then use to look in the correct spot in the gerbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way in GC-Prevue to link pick and place files to Gerbers.

You could get the (x,y) part location from the pick and place file, assuming it's in ASCII format and not something machine readable, and then use that to navigate to the same position in GC-Prevue to find the component.

If whoever is supplying you with the Gerbers doesn't want to share the PCB design files, could you ask them for ODB++ files? It's easier to find components with those.

Comment: It's like night and day.  Used ODB++ as suggested and works brilliantly. Thanks!

Comment: I don't normally give ODB++ files to board manufacturers as I feel they contain too much information making it much more easy to reverse engineer a design.  I'm more happy giving this information to an assembly house because they will have signed an NDA either with my company or my clients company.